# Fail to compile QGIS source on Windows

Tags: qgis, python, compilation

CMake fails to configure. I get following error:

```
Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required
is at least "2.7" (found c:/cygwin/bin/python2.7.exe)
```

which seems irrational. Probably I have found a cause of this behavior. I think that there is a problem with bat file found in [the instruction](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL):

```
@echo off
set VS90COMNTOOLS=%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
call "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86

set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\include
set LIB=%LIB%;%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\lib

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
path %PATH%;%PROGRAMFILES%\CMake\bin;c:\cygwin\bin

@set GRASS_PREFIX=c:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-6.4.4
@set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\include
@set LIB=%LIB%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib

@cmd
```

If I run the bat file and run `c:/cygwin/bin/python2.7.exe` in cmd I get the following error message:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

Running `c:/cygwin/bin/python2.7.exe` in cmd without running bat file works fine.

I have found answers to similar questions but none solves my problem. Please help me. What can I change in bat file to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was clearing `PYTHONHOME` variable. So modified bat I used look like this:

```
@echo off
set VS90COMNTOOLS=%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
call "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86

set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\include
set LIB=%LIB%;%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\lib

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
path %PATH%;%PROGRAMFILES%\CMake\bin;c:\cygwin\bin

@set GRASS_PREFIX=c:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-6.4.4
@set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\include
@set LIB=%LIB%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib

SET PYTHONHOME=

@cmd
```

I will mark this answer as accepted as it worked for me. However if anyone knows the problem and has better answer I would be happy to get to know it.